# What is the relation between Neighbourhood of a point,Interior point and open set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I want to know what is the relation between of Neighbourhood of a point,Interior point and open set?

**Definition:** A set $N \subset \mathbb{R}$ is called the $\textbf{neighbourhood}$ of a point a, if there  exists an interval I containing a and contained in N, i.e ,$$a\in I \subset N $$.

**Definition:**     A point x is an interior point of a set S if S is a nbd of x. In other words, x is an interior point of S if $\exists $ an open interval $(a,b)$ containing x and contained in S , i.e., $$x\in(a,b)\subseteq S$$.

**Definition:** A set S is said to be open if it is a nbd of each of its point, i.e, $x\in S$, there exists an open interval $I_x$ such that $$mx \in I_x \subseteq S $$.

Comment: In the definition of a neighborhood it should really say an *open* interval.

Comment: A set $S$ is open if and only if every point in $S$ is an interior point of $S$

Comment: In the definition of interior point it should say that $S$ contains a neighborhood of $x$ not $S$ is a neighborhood of $x$. Same goes for the definition of open set: $S$ contains a neighborhood, not "is" a neighborhood.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales A set that contains a neighbourhood of $x$ **is** a neighbourhood of $x$.

Comment: I agree with Robert Israel: neighborhoods are not assumed to be open

Comment: @RobertIsrael It depends upon what kind of development is being used. Generally a distinction is made between neighborhoods and open sets, with neighborhoods being more basic with open sets defined in terms of neighborhoods.

Comment: @Shanti I wouldn't say any of them stronger or weaker than the others.  A neighborhood may or may not be an open set so in that sense it's weaker. But it does have to have at the least the point $a$ where an open set doesn't have that restriction and thus could also be considered stronger.  And an interior point isn't even a set, but an element of a set (forgetting the set theorists who will tell you that *everything's* a set).  Perhaps you have a different idea in mind for what **weak** and **strong** mean?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales So why do you object to the OP's definition of  interior point?

Comment: I get idea Thanks to all : )

Comment: @Shanti OK, now that you've edited out the part about weakness and strongness, the remaining question is really answered in the body of your post.  The *definitions themselves* tell you the relationships between the concepts.

Comment: @RobertIsrael  Now that I re-read the OP's definition of neighborhood I see that I have no objection. Essentially the stated definition (corrected to open interval) is synonymous with "open set."

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales OP's definition of neighborhood (corrected to open interval) isn't synonymous with open set.  It's a set which contains an open set containing the point $a$.  That doesn't tell you whether the neighborhood itself is open or not.

Comment: Um, I don't understand your question.  You ask what the relationship is but then you give three definitions that precisely spell out what the relationship is.  So what's the question.  The three definitions answered precisely what you asked.

Comment: @Bye_World  OK, this approach where a neighborhood has only to be an interval, not necessarily open, is unfamiliar to me. But I will assume it is a valid alternate approach.

Comment: These definitions assume the universal set is $\mathbb R$ and that the term "interval" is defined.  But that's okay if you are only defining for subset of R.  (You'll need different but similar definitions for other spaces later.)  There's some strange terminology such as S is  "the" neighborhood rather than "a" neighborhood is a set S such that... (usually I prefer the definition that a neighbor hood be an open interval but this def. will work).  The second two definitions disagree with the first in requiring the interval to be open which isn't nesc.  This is okay but I prefer another...

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Again, you're slightly off.  A neighborhood doesn't have to *be* an open interval, it only has to *contain* an open interval.  The standard topological definition of a neighborhood is thusly: If $X$ is a topological space and $p \in X$, then a neighborhood of $p$ is a subset $V\subseteq X$ that contains an open set $U$ which itself contains $p$. I.e. $p\in U\subseteq V$.  Then in $\Bbb R$ with the *standard topology*, the open sets are precisely the sets containing an open interval around each point in the set.  Thus OP's def is equivalent given the change to *open* interval.

Comment: What is the question? I suggest that we transcend the space ${\mathbb R}$ when discussing such matters.

Comment: Actually I think it does have to be an open interval in def 1.  Let $a \in S =  [a, \infty)$ then $[a, b] \subset S$ and $a \in [a,b]$.  But S should not be allowed to be a neighborhood of $a$ as absolutely no points immediately to the left of $a$ are in S.  Intuitively a neighborhood should "surround" a and there should be points to both sides.

Comment: @Bye_World   Being in my eighth decade I will take your word for what is now standard for the meaning of 'neighborhood.' It is not a term I ever used in topology, where the terms 'point' and 'region' were the basic undefined terms and a set $U$ was open if and only if for $x\in U$ there was a region $D$ containing $x$ such that $D\subset U$.  In the topology of the real line, 'region' was interpreted to mean 'open interval.'

Comment: In definition 1.  What does "containing" mean.  I'd say [a,b] "contains" both a and b, but we *can't* say [a,b] is a neighborhood of a or of b.  If we could then we'd have to say [a,b] is open as each point, including a and be have the neighborhood $a \in [a,b] \subset [a,b]$.

Comment: @fleablood My very first comment (which is also *the* very first comment) says that definition should really say *open* interval.  OP's definition is not correct as is.

Comment: I agree but it was later stated that the definition of neighborhood is that a neighbor hood need not be open.  Which is also true.  And it seemed for a while that your first comment was being disagreed with.  I don't think it was pointed out that even though a neighborhood need not be open and can contain a closed interval it must actually contain an open interval.  And I don't think it was confirmed you first comment *did* need to be correct.  Sorry if you thought I was repeating you.

Answer (score 8):

Intuitively:

- A neighbourhood of a point is a set that *surrounds* that point. That is, if you move a sufficiently small (but non-zero) amount away from that point, you won't leave the set.
- An interior point of a set is a point that *is surrounded by* the set. Note that this is really the same relation, only the subject has changed.
- An open set is one which surrounds *all* its points. That is, *wherever* you are in that set, a sufficiently small move will not get you out.

Comment: What is the difference between interior point and neighbourhood?

Comment: @NewBornMATH: An interior point is a point, a neighbourhood is a set of points. In particular, the set $N$ is a neighbourhood of the point $x$ iff the point $x$ is an interior point of the set $N$.

Answer (score 3):

General definitions:

1. Neighborhood: a neighborhood of a point $x$ is a set that contain some open set that contains $x$. For the case of the standard topology of $\Bbb R$ an open set in composed of arbitrary union of open intervals, and the minimal expression of an open set is an open interval. Then if a set $S$ contain some open interval $I$ that contain $x$ then $S$ is a neighborhood of $x$, i.e.

$$x\in I\text{ and } I\subseteq S\iff S\text{ is a neighborhoof of } x $$

(for the standard topology of $\Bbb R$)

2. Interior point: an interior point of a set $S$ is a point of an open set $U$ contained in $S$. For the case of the standard topology on $\Bbb R$ because every open set is composed of the union of open intervals (that are the minimal expression of open sets in the standard topology of $\Bbb R$) then this mean that $x$ is a interior point of $S$ if exists some open interval $I$ that contains $x$ and $I$ is contained in $S$, i.e.

$$x\in I\text{ and }I\subseteq S\iff x\text{ is an interior point of } S$$

(for the standard topology of $\Bbb R$)

3. Open set: the open sets are the definition of a topology in some space, i.e. the collection of subsets $\mathcal T$ of some space $G$ is a topology of $G$ if and only if

   - the empty set and $G$ belongs to $\mathcal T$
   - the arbitrary union of elements of $\mathcal T$ belongs to $\mathcal T$
   - the finite intersection of elements of $\mathcal T$ belongs to $\mathcal T$

Any element of $\mathcal T$ is named an open set. The standard topology of $\Bbb R$ contains all open intervals, so it contains too the arbitrary union of open intervals, the empty set, $\Bbb R$ itself and any finite intersection of all these elements.

Answer (score 2):

It might help to look at a simple example.  Let $S = [0,1]$.  This is a neighbourhood of each point of $(0,1)$, but not a neighbourhood of $0$ or $1$.
Since it is not a neighbourhood of $0$ or $1$, and those points are in $S$, it is not an open set.  The interior of $S$ is $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'm going to give an analysis metric space definition.

Preliminary:  First we need to consider what "universe" we are defining these points and sets to belong to.  The OP seems to be assuming this universe is $\mathbb R$ which is fine.  But it could be $\mathbb R^k$ as well.  Or it could be more abstract and simply be any "metric space".  I am *not* going to explain what a metric space is here but simply say it is a "universe" of points where somehow a distance between two points is somehow defined.  In $\mathbb R$ the distance between $x$ and $y$ is $|x - y|$.  In $\mathbb R^k$ it is $||x, y|| = \sqrt{x^2 - y^2}$.  It doesn't matter how distance is defined just that it is.

First:  If we have a point $x$ we need somehow to describe the idea of "a bunch of points that immediately surround $x$ in all directions".

If our universe is $\mathbb R$ any interval $I = (a,b)$ where $a < x < b$ will do.  So will $[a,b]$ where $a < x <b$.  But $[x,b]$ or $[x,b)$ will not as it doesn't include any points immediately to the left of $x$.

In $\mathbb R^2$ for $(x,y)$ is could be a rectangle $[a,b] \times [c,d]$ where $a < x < b$ and $c < y < d$.  or it could be the disc centered at $(a,c)$ with radius $r$ st $(a - x)^2+ (c -y)^2 < r^2$.

Or if it's any metric space in general, I like to define a "open ball" as set $N = $ "all the points, $z$ so that $||x,z|| < d$ for some distance $d$.

But it doesn't matter which of these methods we use to find "a bunch of points immediately surrounding $x$ in all directions".  Any one of them will do

As the OP wants to use an interval we will.  But it needs to be an open interval.  $x \in [x, b]$ simply won't do as it doesn't include any points immediately to the left of $x$.

.....

Okay now we can start!

A **neighborhood** of $x$ is any set that contains ""a bunch of points that immediately surround $x$ in all directions".

In other words: *Definition*:  A set $S$ is a **neighborhood** of $x$ if there is an open interval $I_x$ such that $x \in I_x$ (in other words that $I_x = (a,b)$ and $a < x < b$) and $I_x \subset S$.

It actually wouldn't change things very much to define that a nieghborhood *is* an open interval.  It wouldn't hurt things but it wouldn't help things either.  I'm personally *very* used to defining a neighborhood as *being* an "open ball" as I described above.  (In $\mathbb R$ an open ball is the exact same thing as the open interval $(x - d, x + d)$).

But we will use the open interval criterion as a definition.

So.... *a neighborhood is any set around* x *that contains points that "completely surround"*  x  *i.e.  a set that contains an open interval containing* x.

Now interior points:  An *interior* point of a set $S$, is a point in $S$ that is completely surrounded by points of $S$.  If for example $S = [a,b]$ then if $a < x < b$ then$x$ is "smack dab in the middle" and absolutely surrounded by points of $S$.  But the two points $a$ and $b$ are not.  All points *except* $a$ and $b$ are interior points of $S$.

**Definition**: A point $x \in S$ is an **interior point** of $S$ is a neighborhood of $x$.  In other words $x \in S$ is an interior point of $S$ if there exists an open interval $I_x$ so that $x \in I_x \subset S$.

**Definition**: A set $S$ is **open** if every point in $S$ is an interior point of $S$.  In other words, for *all* $x \in S$ there are open intervals (maybe very small) such that $x \in I_x \subset S$.

Example: consider $S = (-\infty, 3] \cup (5, 7]$.  $S$ is not open because $3$ and $7$ are not interior points.  There is no $(a,b)$ so that $a < 3 < b$ and $(a,b) \subset S$.  Same thing for $7$.

But all other points are interior points.  If $x < 3$ then $(x-1, 3) \subset S$ so $x$ is interior point.  If $5 < y < 7$ then $(5,7)\subset S$ so $y$ is an interior point.

So $W = (-\infty, 3) \cup (5,7)$ would be open.

...

So the relationship...

A neighborhood of a point surrounds the point completely (but maybe only for a very small distance).

An interior point of a set is a point in the set that is completely surrounded by the set.

A set if open if every point in the set is completely surrounded by other points in the set.  (In other words no point is on the "edge" of the set where "right next to it" the set "ends".)